# What happens to existing virtual server connections when I update an iRule?

Tags: f5-big-ip

I have a HA pair of F5 BIG-IP devices running version `11.5.3 Build 1.0.167 Hotfix HF1`. I currently have an iRule attached to about 200 virtual servers which enables high-speed logging for certain types of events. I need to update this iRule, but I'm worried about what will happen to existing connections. Will they be broken or continue running using the old version of the iRule? Many of these virtual servers are for our ERP systems, so connection interruptions are basically unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, when you save the iRule, existing connections will continue to use the old version, while new connections will use the update.

https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13253

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I'm just trying to be absolutely sure before I make changes in production.

Comment: Hmm, trying to find an actual source for you, but coming up empty. It is tribal knowledge though.

Comment: Edited my answer to include source.